# convert a string of variables to variable

Tags: javascript, php, string, variables

I have a String of javascript variables like this in a PHP varaible:

```
var TopInst='0',LVal18AFC='ولپارس',DEven='0',LSecVal='ساير واسطه گريهاي مالي',CgrValCot='N2',Flow='1',InstrumentID='IRO1LPRS0001',InsCode='48241092863917835',BaseVol=9140768,EstimatedEPS='341',ZTitad=2000000000,CIsin='IRO1LPRS0007',LVal18AFC='ولپارس',CSecVal='58 ',PdrCotVal='',PClosing='',PSGelStaMax='5570.00',PSGelStaMin='5160.00',Title='ليزينگ پارسيان (ولپارس) - بازار دوم بورس',FaraDesc ='',MinWeek='5220.00',MaxWeek='5720.00',MinYear='3200.00',MaxYear='9450.00',QTotTran5JAvg='26445809',SectorPE='12.91',KAjCapValCpsIdx='23',PriceMin=0,PriceMax=0,PriceYesterday=0;ThemeCount='5';ContractSize='0';NAV='0.0000';
```

and I want to convert it to real javascript or PHP variables so what do you suggest?

split the string or some other way?

Thanks.

Comment: As written, you have a number of variables created an initialized in JavaScript with that code. Are you sending this in an `echo` from PHP? What actually shows up in the rendered HTML?

Comment: Hey, I'm using curl to get a website data script data and this is the script and I need these variables to work within PHP ...